# Firebase Google login issue with popup

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am building firebase google authentication, it works fine. The issue I am having is I want popup to always open. As of now it opens and sees if there is any email account logged in, if yes it picks up that email account and tries to login without even asking if I want to select another account for signing up. This works fine if there is no email account logged in on browser or if there are more than 1 accounts logged in, then the popup asks which account I would like to select. I want the same behavior when there is one account logged in.

Comment: Can you clarify the question? what you want if that when user is already logged to show the popup asking wich mail account to use? in that case just subscribe to the authState and call the login method if the person is already inside the system

Comment: I want it to always ask which account to use for login.